# XYZ Tile Layer maps too small to read

Tags: qgis, text

I believe similar questions on this subject have been asked, but I can't figure out how to solve my problem.  I have added an OpenStreetMap layer and a Google Maps layer to a QGIS project (version 3.20).  The text on the maps is too small to read at all zoom levels.  As I zoom in, the text on the maps appears larger for a moment, then becomes very small.  The CRS for the project and the maps is the same.

Comment: Please include links to the earlier Q&As that you mention.